Efficient binning in numpy with fancy indexing
I have a stack of 2D images which I would like to bin into a smaller image with arbitrary pixel boundaries.  I have an example below which utilizes bins defined using boolean arrays and fancy indexing, however it uses too much memory (specifically the Image Binning section). Is there a better way to do this binning in Numpy without resorting to slow for-loops?
Eventually I hope to do binning with image stack shape (50, 1024, 1024) → (50, 100, 100).


#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.data import camera

# --- Setup Test Image and Sizes ---

# shape of original images
num_images, width, height = 1, 128, 128
images = np.empty((num_images, width, height))
images[:] = camera()[::4, ::4]

# shape of polar binned image
pol_width, pol_height = 40, 45

# --- Generate Polar Bin Indices ---

# generate boolean mask for every polar pixel
x, y = np.meshgrid(
    np.arange(width) - (width // 2),
    (height // 2) - np.arange(height)
)
r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
theta = np.arctan2(y, x)

r_bins = np.linspace(0, r.max(), pol_width + 1)
theta_bins = np.linspace(theta.min(), theta.max(), pol_height + 1)

# define polar bins which will be used in fancy indexing
r_mask = np.logical_and(
    r[None, :, :] > r_bins[:-1, None, None],
    r[None, :, :] <= r_bins[1:, None, None],
)
theta_mask = np.logical_and(
    theta[None, :, :] >= theta_bins[:-1, None, None],
    theta[None, :, :] < theta_bins[1:, None, None],
)

# --- Image Binning ---

# shape: (num_images, pol_width, pol_height, width, height)
images_polar = (
    images[:, None, None, :, :]
    * r_mask[None, :, None, :, :]
    * theta_mask[None, None, :, :, :]
)
# shape: (num_images, pol_width, pol_height)
result = images_polar.sum(axis=-1).sum(axis=-1)

# scale summed result by number of pixels in each bin
pix_counts = (r_mask[:, None, :, :] * theta_mask[None, :, :, :]).sum(axis=-1).sum(axis=-1)
result /= pix_counts[None, :, :]

# --- Plot ---

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10, 5])
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(images[0])
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2, polar=True)
r_centers = (r_bins[1:] + r_bins[:-1]) / 2
theta_centers = (theta_bins[1:] + theta_bins[:-1]) / 2
plt.pcolormesh(theta_centers, r_centers, result[0])
plt.show()

Bonus question:  Is there a technique which will work when r_mask and theta_mask contain pixel weights as floats instead of bools to do fractional binning?

I see a polar transform. you should do a polar transform. then your areas become simple rectangular slices. -- sure, any fractional values are merely to be multiplied with the source image, before summing. that's more foreplay than bonus. -- if your code is slow, use numba. if that's still slow, replace arbitrary numpy calls by hand-written code. that'll actually be compiled, instead of calling numpy.
